# Avoiding header conflicts when creating and depoying Static Libraries in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, static-libraries

I have created a static library in iOS where I have certain common functionality for my projects.  I used the instructions for the [iOS Universal Framework](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework) and everything works great.

I have a module in the static library that requires `AFNetworking`.  So I installed the cocoapods, and included it in my static library

However, when I include my static library into another project that also needs `AFNetworking`, and I run the project, I get a duplicate symbol error for all the common classes.

What is the best approach to avoid a conflict like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is not to include any 3rd-party libraries / frameworks inside your framework.

Here's [Apple reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/CreationGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002254-BAJHGGGA) regarding "How to build your own framework". There are a lot of guidelines that will help to build a good framework that will not cause any errors if you'll link it to any project.

`AFNetworking` is a framework that is application specific, so you should not include it into your framework. You may `weak`ly  link your framework to `AFNetworking`, but you should avoid strongly linking it.

Here's resource regarding [weak linking](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002378-BBCJICEC).

For example, if you are using 3rd-party library, you should specify that your framework require user to add dependencies in order to use it.
Here's [an example](http://cocoapods.org) how AFNetworking does it.
Also, check [this framework](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK#requirements), and it's requirements regarding dependencies in its specification.

Comment: Thanks, your answer seems sensible in the sense you should avoid linking 3rd party libraries on your own.  However i think there are situations where you want to build a feature on top of other frameworks like encapsulating an upload to S3 (requiring AWS SDK) or you need to use OpenSSL, etc.   There should be a way to run a script and remove certain headers when you build your library.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this (in my opinion) is to underscore the class names to keep them unique.

So let's say your library is called `XYLibrary`. It will have a bunch of AFNetworking files like `AFNetworking.h` and `AFNetworking.m`. Rename those to `XY_AFNetworking.h` and `XY_AFNetworking.m`. This should hopefully keep them unique from other instances of that library in another project.

You should do this for any other 3rd party libraries as well.